# Detect specific string structure with numeric shortform date pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm struggling to write a suitable Regex to detect a string which includes a specific pattern (version number) and a short form date. This string comes from a Serialport in an Electron app I'm building.

The string is in the below three patterns based on the hardware which responds, but is often in between `\r\n` and possibly other strings:

`MyHardwareName Vn.nn dd/mm/yy` ⇒ (MyHardware V1.23 01/02/03)
`MyHardwareName Vnn.nn dd/mm/yy` ⇒ (MyHardware V12.34 01/02/03)
`MyHardwareName Vn.nn dd/mm/yyyy` ⇒ (MyHardware V1.23 01/02/2003)
`MyHardwareName Vnn.nn dd/mm/yyyy` ⇒ (MyHardware V12.34 01/02/2003)

The closest I've got so far is by just detecting the date and manually processing after and looking for a string starting with the transmitted command up to the CRLF. This isn't reliable and I sometimes end up with pieces of the next line. Not to mention, the `.split()` returns the match in multiple pieces which isn't ideal.

### My Attempts

#### Data response to run regex on

```
hardware -v
...(need to ignore junk here in case there is any)
MyHardware V1.23 01/02/20     (This is the only line I need)
PROCESSOR:xxxxxxxxxx
abc <n> <c> [r]     
def <n> <c> [r]     
...
```

#### Regex:

`/([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{0,2}/`
-> Consistently captures the line after the date too

`/(hardware -v\s+)(.*)(\r\n)/`
→ Returns:

```
["hardware -v", "My ", "Hardware V1.10 06/02/15", "
↵PROCESSOR:SAMD51J19A"]
```

Ultimately I want to be able to split a string with a regex and obtain "MyHardware V1.10 06/02/15" (or one of the above variations where version is 2 digits and the year being 4 digits).

Can anybody advise on if this is possible to do in one Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match 1+ times a word character (or `MyHardware` hardcoded) followed by a captial `V` and a version number 1-2 digits, a dot and 1-2 digits followed by a date like pattern, you might use:

```
^\w+(?:[ \t]\w+)*[ \t]+V\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[ \t]+(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])\/(?:1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(?:20)?[0-9]{2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/17ttUL/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+(?:[ \t]\w+)*` Match 1+ times a word char with an optional repeated part that matches a space or tab and again 1+ times a word char
- `[ \t]+V` Match 1+ times a space or tab and `V`
- `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits, `.` and 1-2 digits
- `[ \t]+` Match 1+ times a space or tab
- `(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])\/(?:1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(?:20)?[0-9]{2}` Match a date like pattern

Note that the date like pattern does not validate a date itself and if you don't want to match a tab, you could replace `[ \t]` with a space in the [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/lRyD57/1).

```js
const regex = /^\w+(?:[ \t]\w+)*[ \t]+V\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[ \t]+(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])\/(?:1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(?:20)?[0-9]{2}/gm;
const str = `hardware -v
...(need to ignore junk here in case there is any)
MyHardware V1.23 01/02/20     (This is the only line I need)
PROCESSOR:xxxxxxxxxx
abc <n> <c> [r]
def <n> <c> [r]


MyHardware V1.23 01/02/03
MyHardware V12.34 01/02/03
MyHardware V1.23 01/02/2003
MyHardware V12.34 01/02/2003
My Hardware V1.23 01/02/20`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for such an extensive response. Works great on the above strings, I'd also realised I forgot to add the "gm" global/match characters! Only thing is the above doesn't match when there might be a space between "MyHardware". Example: "My Hardware V1.23 01/02/20" doesn't match

Comment: @user5156141 Try this updated version https://regex101.com/r/A0OBq0/2https://regex101.com/r/A0OBq0/3

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/A0OBq0/3 Worked perfectly. Thank you very much, time to study it!

Answer (score 0):

**Regex1**

```
/(^[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(V[\d\.]+)\s+(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/img
```

**Results**

MyHardware V1.23 01/02/03

MyHardware V12.34 01/02/03

MyHardware V1.23 01/02/2003

MyHardware V12.34 01/02/2003

**Regex2**

```
(.*)(\d\d)(\d\d)$     find

$1$2                  replace
```

**Results**

MyHardware V1.23 01/02/03

MyHardware V12.34 01/02/03

MyHardware V1.23 01/02/03

MyHardware V12.34 01/02/03